# Flask can't see my virtual hosting's IP address

Tags: python, flask, ip

I was trying to run my flask script with no debug on my domain (linux):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0")
```

but when started it said this:

```
* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://127.0.4.49:5000
```

and there wasn't my site. It basically doesn't see my ip address and doesn't count it at all when typing it into `app.run(host)` parameters. what should I do?

Typing virtual machine's actual ip address didn't work:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: try `debug=True` and check whether you get more stack trace. Also you can create a simple server by using `python3 -m http.server 5000` and it will run a lightweight server which lists index of current directory. Try to access that server using public ip

Comment: You might have overlook *"Running on all addresses"*. It literally means **all** addresses.